# Is the DirectShow "Infinite Pin Tee Filter" part of all Windows XP and Windows 7 versions?

Tags: filter, directshow

I'm about to use the DirectShow "Infinite Pin Tee Filter" in one of my Filter Graphs.  I want to know if I can rely on it being present in all Windows XP and Windows 7 boxes my application is installed on, 64-bit too?  Or is there an AX file I need to find/create and add to my installation program including running regsvr32 on it at install time?

Also, is there any harm in always including it in my filter graph or should I only include it when I need it, which would sometimes have it in the filter graph with only a single output pin?  The filter graph I create is configurable to send audio to a file, a renderer, or both.

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) It has a small overhead, but you are not going to notice it.

Comment: @RomanR - Interesting update.  I had to pull out the Tee Filter when I didn't need it.  For some reason, if it was inline when I only had a Renderer connected, but without aparallel output connection to a Render Filter, the Renderer was throwing up a failed HRESULT when the second (not first) buffer was delivered to it's input pin.  I thought it might be a timestamp issue but when I took out the Tee Filter the error stopped happening immediately and the timestamp generation code is identical between those two use case scenarios.

Comment: Inf filter attempts to be transparent for the filter it is inserted in between, but this deinitely is not the case when the filter have some intimate connection details, such as dynamic format changes. That is, if you have issues you should remove it or possibly work issues around. If it stays there and works, the overhead is small and is basiccally OK to neglect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Infinite Pin Tee Filter" is registered in the "qcap.dll" so it should be in all Windows systems. qcap.dll already exists in Win98, maybe earlier. So it should be no problem. And if it sometimes disappear, Microsoft has provided the [sourcecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as DirectShow SDK example.